what is the correct way to connect multiple api to 1 blazor website?
I have a blazor server web app and multiple API's. Each of those api's lead to a different location.
I currently change the location to where it needs to go based on a parameter that i then pass along to every function like so:
    public class ActiviteitenClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = httpClient;
        public async Task<List<OActiviteit>> GetAsync(string adres = "")
        {
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new(adres);
            var y = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/api/Activiteit");
            var z = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<OActiviteit>>(await y.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            return z;
        }...

there has to be a better way to do this. Can anyone enlighten me how?

This may be of interest to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Have a look at YARP. I use app.MapForwarder(pattern: $"/api/{endpoint}/{{**catch-all}}", destinationPrefix); from Microsoft.Extensions.ServiceDiscovery.Yarp specifically transformations for your parameter problem.
